# I found this error with gradle on run my flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter

That is the error when I run my app - I need some help.

I added the library `just_audio:0:9:31` and I got this error and didn't run

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
>
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
>
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.18.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.11.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.1)
>
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.18.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.18.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.11.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.1)
>
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 15s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I expect to find some advice to solve it

Answer (score 1):

in your `android/app/build.gradle`, try adding those dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    def exoplayer_version = "2.18.1" // this is the version 
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:$exoplayer_version"
}
```

save and re build your app.

Comment: it returns the same error.
it didn't work.